# Preg_match: Get value between text

Tags: php, regex

Pattern: `"/CN=(.*)\,/"`

String: `CN=João Pedro Mantovani,OU=host,DC=ghw,DC=college,DC=br`

I'm trying to get the text between `CN=` and the first `,` after the text but i'm getting all the content until the last comma

```
array(
  0 =>  CN=João Pedro Mantovani,OU=host,DC=ghw,DC=college,
  1 =>  João Pedro Mantovani,OU=host,DC=ghw,DC=college
)
```

How i can get just the text between `CN=` and the first `,`? In this case, `João Pedro Mantovani`

Comment: Use not-greedy question mark operator: `/CN=(.*?)\,/`

Comment: CN=(.*?), Yep, use the question mark.

Comment: the above work non-greed or just do not comma `([^,]+),`

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: It looks like you're parsing LDAP data.  You may get better results by using the LDAP functionality that is already in PHP.  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a "`?`" to the inner pattern, it will become non-greedy

try `/CN=(.*?)\,/`
and the result might be what you want.

Comment: this will only get the first CN not any of the other items